# Execute code in server.R depending on active tabPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

assume you have a user interface with a navbar like this:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Shiny APP",
      tabPanel("Welcome",
               p("Welcome!")),
      navbarMenu("Kapitel 1",
                 tabPanel("PANEL 1",withMathJax(),
                          h3("Topic 1"),
                          fluidRow(column(4),column(8)),
                          fluidRow(column(12))
                 ),
                 tabPanel("PANEL 2",withMathJax(),
                          h3("Topic 2"),
                          fluidRow(column(4) ,column(8))
                 ))                 
)
```

Clearly, in "Panel 1" and "Panel 2" I will have displayed different output.
How can I make the execution of code in server.R dependent on which Panel is active?

Lets say I have two different plots. If Panel 1 is active, R is supposed to ONLY execute all the code for the first Panel/Plot.
If Panel 2 is active, R is supposed to ONLY execute all the code for the second Panel/Plot.

I hope I made it clear :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, it worked for me to write `if(navbarMenu==1)` (for example). For that to work, you should write for each tabPanel `tabPanel("PANEL 1",value=1, ...)`